# UILabel with Gesture Recognizer inside UITableViewCell blocks didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer, didselectrowatindexpath

I use some UILabels with a `UITapGestureRecognizer` inside a `UITableViewCell`. The GestureRecognizer works well. But when I tap on the label, I want that the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` should execute too. Or even just the `indexPathForSelectedRow()` method should give me the selected row.

Setting `cancelsTouchesInView = false` did not work!

Is this possible? Right now the `indexPathForSelectedRow()` method returns nil.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using `UITapGestureRecognizer`?  If you want to use that, try to set the tag of label as `label.tag=indexpath.row`. So you might get the value you are looking at. Regarding my own opinion, I'd  remove the `uitapgesturerecognizer` and directly use `didselectrowatindexpath` method..

EDIT 2:

Try using this solution..it might help you..

```
 -(void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender

   {

CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:self.view];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint([self.view convertRect:self.yourTableView.frame fromView:self.tableView.superview], location))
    {
        CGPoint locationInTableview = [self.yourTableView convertPoint:location fromView:self.view];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.yourTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:locationInTableview];
        if (indexPath)
            [self tableView:self.yourTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: I use more than one labels

Comment: What are you going to do by using UITapGestureRecognizer??

Comment: I have three labels that when I tap them, they store a different value into an array, and I need the selected row for the array index

Comment: @MiteshTrivedi Thank you for this solution. I was trying to get a tap gesture working inside a tableviewCell and I stumbled upon your post. Thank you for sharing your insight!