# Passing String Value of a NSManagedObject attribute to a new view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

I have a `tableView` populated with `NSString` values from an `NSFetchedResultsController`. I have the cells configured to check/uncheck cells. That works perfectly.

I'm trying to configure the cells so clicking one of the labels within the cell triggers a segue to another view controller. I configured the label and threw a log statement in where I'd like to do the segue and everything works properly. When I add the segue, get no compiler errors, but it crashes at runtime with the follow error:

```
2015-05-31 08:09:04.656 MyApp[17682:1240919] -[UIViewController selectedItemPhoto:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa42b65d4e0
2015-05-31 08:09:04.694 MyApp[17682:1240919] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController selectedItemPhoto:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa42b65d4e0'
```

I'm fairly certain I'm doing something startlingly stupid, but I'm stumped as to what. I welcome suggestions.

**MyCustomCell.h:**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *itemDescription;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *itemGroup;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *itemImage;
```

**FirstVC.m methods:**

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // implement custom cell
    MyCustomCell *customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Get a hold of myManagedObject from FRC
    MyNSManagedObject *myObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configures 1st label to look like a hyperlink
    customCell.itemDescription.text = myObject.itemDescription;
    customCell.itemDescription.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    customCell.itemDescription.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    // Enables gesture and sets demoObject to pass along via the segue called from labelTap
    UITapGestureRecognizer *labelTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelTap)];
    [customCell.itemDescription addGestureRecognizer:labelTapGesture];
    self.demoObject = myObject;

    // Configures 2nd label within customCell
    customCell.itemGroup.text = myObject.itemGroup;
    // add image to cell, already imported into Images.xcassets
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-1.jpg", myObject.photo];
    customCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

    // The following code ensures random checkmarks don't appear when the user scrolls.
    if ([self.selectedObjects containsObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]]) {
        customCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        customCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return customCell;
}
```

`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    self.selectedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Set the checkmark accessory for the selected row.
    if ([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        [self.selectedObjects addObject:self.selectedObject];
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    } else {
        [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
        [self.selectedObjects removeObject:self.selectedObject];
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }

    // Enables save button if there are items in the selectedObjects array
    if (self.selectedObjects.count > 0) {
        [self.saveButton setEnabled:YES];
    } else {
        [self.saveButton setEnabled:NO];
    }   
}
```

`labelTap` method

```
- (void) labelTap {
    // The "hyperlink" effect I'm trying to achieve works without the segue
    NSLog(@"itemDescription tapped");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:nil];
}
```

`prepareForSegue` method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"mySegue"] && self.demoObject != nil) {
        // This line returns a value...
        NSLog(@"self.demoObject = %@", self.demoObject.itemDescription);
        // ...but it crashes here when it tries to set on the destinationViewController
        SecondViewController *destinationViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        destinationViewController.selectedItemPhoto = self.demoObject.photo;
        destinationViewController.selectedItemTitle = self.demoObject.itemDescription;
    }
}
```

**SecondViewController.h properties**

```
// The photo is a string that references a filename in my app
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *selectedItemPhoto;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *selectedItemTitle;
```

Comment: Where do you define "mySegue"? In your storyboard?

Comment: do you segue to "regular" viewController or to a TabBarController or NavigationController or something along that lines?

Comment: We're making some progress here! I dragged from the customCell to SecondVC. If I don't click the label, it segues and checks my cell. I'd like to click the label to do a segue, but if I'm not clicking the label, I just want to check/uncheck the cell. I think I'm trying to do this segue incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I had three issues (two were tied together):

**Issue 1:** Juan Catalan pointed out I didn't have my storyboard set for `SecondViewController`

**Issue 2:** Yuchen & luk2302 raised the issue of how I'm performing the segue.

**Issue 3:** I don't need `prepareForSegue`

Here's what I did:

**1:** I removed `prepareForSegue`.

**2:** I removed the storyboard segue.

**2:** I altered `labelTap` method to add a parameter for the `labelTapGesture`

```
- (void) labelTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"stretchDescription tapped");

    CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:self.view];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint([self.view convertRect:self.tableView.frame fromView:self.tableView.superview], location)) {
        CGPoint locationInTableview = [self.tableView convertPoint:location fromCoordinateSpace:self.view];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:locationInTableview];
        if (indexPath) {
            self.demoObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            DisplayStretchViewController *destinationViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondVC"];

            // Set properties on destinationVC
            destinationViewController.itemPhoto = self.demoObject.photo;
            destinationViewController.itemTitle = self.demoObject.stretchDescription;
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:destinationViewController animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

I also found this post extremely helpful:
[UILabel with Gesture Recognizer inside UITableViewCell blocks didSelectRowAtIndexPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392775/uilabel-with-gesture-recognizer-inside-uitableviewcell-blocks-didselectrowatinde)

Thank you to all for your input!

Answer (score 1):

From the error it seems you did not set the class of your second view controller. It seems it is `UIViewController` and should be `SecondViewController`.

In your storyboard select the second view controller and set its class to `SecondViewController`.

Another advice is that in Objective C you should use introspection before casting an object. So in your code I would add:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"mySegue"] && self.demoObject != nil) {
        // This line returns a value...
        NSLog(@"self.demoObject = %@", self.demoObject.itemDescription);
        // ...but it crashes here when it tries to set on the destinationViewController
        if ([[segue destinationViewController] isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]]) {
            SecondViewController *destinationViewController = (SecondViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
            destinationViewController.selectedItemPhoto = self.demoObject.photo;
            destinationViewController.selectedItemTitle = self.demoObject.itemDescription;
        }
    }
}
```

In this way the segue won't happen but the app won't crash.

Comment: Thank you! You ID'd one problem I had, but the underlying issue remains. Basically, I want to segue if the label's clicked, but check/uncheck if it's not clicked.

Comment: Use a `UIButton` instead of a `UILabel` and you will be able to define a segue from the button. This should solve your problem.